# VB.Net find the word in textbox and counting

Tags: regex, vb.net, search, counter

I want to find the specific word in the textbox, and I want to count it.

For example,

There is TextBox which contains "abababababab" (6 ab)

and there is another textbox wich contains "ab"

And I want to get the result : 6.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
Dim text As String = "abababababab"
Dim find As String = "ab"
Dim result As Integer = CInt((text.Length - text.Replace(find, "").Length) / find.Length)
```

Answer (score 2):

also this way :

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
```

+++++++

```
    Dim txt As String
    txt = "abababababab"
    Dim count As Integer
    count = Regex.Matches(txt, Regex.Escape("ab")).Count()
```

Comment: did this help you??
if yes pleas mark as accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Replace the matching chars in the first string with empty strings, then subtract from the lenght of the original string the length of the resulting string, finally divide by the lenght of the matching string

```
Dim test = "abababababab"
Dim result = test.Replace("ab", "")
Dim len = (test.Length - result.Length) / "ab".Length
Console.WriteLine(len)
```